How to convert shell .stl file to solid in Abaqus?
I understand that after import STL file in the plug-ins, you can convert it to a solid by using 'Create geometry from mesh'. However, the model I want to convert to a solid is a shell, so the 'Create geometry from mesh' option doesn't appear. If anyone knows how to convert a shell STL to a solid in Abaqus, please share any information you have. Thank you.

Does the shell mesh fully enclose a volume?
